# Python, bat file, and Task Scheduler to rename and move files - not working properly in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, os.path

I have two python scripts to rename, zip, and move files from a local computer to a server. The scripts work properly when executed in python, and they work if I execute the .bat file. However, using Task Scheduler, no error messages occur, but the files do not get moved.

The .bat file is:

```
C:\Python27.python.exe "C:\Users\user\Desktop\daily_rename.py"
C:\Python27.python.exe "C:\Users\user\Desktop\daily_zipping.py"
```

It looks like when it is run through Task Scheduler the files that need to be renamed/zipped cannot be found, so I end up with an empty zip folder. I use os.path.join to create all the file names, is this part of the problem?

Comment: Python 2 is dead, don't build new code on it. Use Python 3 instead. Concerning your problems, you are not giving enough info to reproduce it, see also [ask]. When extracting a [mcve], please also pay attention to the different execution contexts when running from an interactive session and when running from a service.

Comment: I don't see any batch-file code in your question. Don't see anything python code in your question. I do not see any details on how you configured Task Scheduler.  Your question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Without seeing the Python scripts in question, I can only guess that either the scripts make an unwarranted assumption that the working directory is the script directory or that they're relying on mapped drives that are not available in the logon-session context of the scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

Check which user account the task has been set to run under. It might not have permission to access the files.